# What happens if a NSURLSessionDataTask response arrives when the delegate finishedWithError is busy?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Suppose I have a NSURLSessionDataTask created for two tasks. Let's say I consecutively make calls to the tasks one after another, and that the response to the second task finishes while the first task response has not arrived. So, now I have the delegate DidFinishWithError running and processing the response for the second task. While the delegate is running, if the response for the first task arrives, what would happen to the delegate method?

Would it finish its method for the second task response (which came first) and then start all over from beginning to process the logic for the first task response?

I am wondering how it works. I tried it out and it seems in this kind of a situation, the call to the first task (which takes longer than the second task to respond back with data) is made again back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLSession` has a `delegateQueue` property, which you can set at creation time. All delegate methods will be called on this queue. If the queue is busy, then it will be like any other - methods won't be executed until the queue can take them.

In your example, the first completion handler would have to return before the second could be executed.